# Simulating the averaging of temperature of two connected water bodies

Tags: python, simulation

For my master thesis in Computer Science, I am required to build a climate simulator in object-oriented fashion. My main struggle right now is finding a formula for averaging the temperature of two bodies of water, or more broadly, **how to average the temperature of two connected objects in the universe**

For example, there is a container of water for which one half contains water at 50°C, and the other half, exactly the same mass and volume of water at 52°C. How will the temperature of that body of water will evolve over time with discrete steps?

[image: Water]

I've looked into Heat Equation but it doesn't quite satisfy me, since I would need something discrete in time **and** space. My simulation uses a "frame rate", refreshing and updating the simulation 100 times per real-world physical second. It works fine for small steps but breaks when time_scale gets closer to 1 or above, in which case each body of water ends up with a temperature higher than the average

So I was wondering if there was some kind of physical formula to average the temperature of two abstract bodies by contact, omitting all other types of heat transfer such as convection, black-body radiation, etc .. ?

A snippet of my current code

```
    def update(self, time_scale=0.001):
        for n in self._neighbours:
            diff = self.get_diff(n)
            self.temperature += time_scale * diff["temperature"]/2
            n.temperature -= time_scale * diff["temperature"]/2
```

get_diff simply returns a dictionnary of the difference of all attributes between two objects

Comment: fwiw they probably just mix via convection if the separator is impossibly thin and instantaneously removed, environment is a perfect insulator, etc.

Comment: I'd suggest searching and then asking if you don't find a good solution in the [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) site instead, and then returning if you have a more-explicit programming question